# Path is present, Permissions are okay, but still getting error

Tags: linux, php, centos, ssh

I recently installed pdftk using instruction provided at stack [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146766/how-do-i-install-pdftk-on-my-server)

I installed it, and run the commanded `whereis pdftk` the result was

```
/usr/local/bin/pdftk    /usr/bin/pdftk
```

I have the powerpannel access and I saw it through it that pdftk actually exists at the location

i run the command `pdftk --version`, it was okay

but when in php i use

```
<?php
$command = "pdftk --help";
system("PATH=/usr/local/bin/ && $command",$response);
if ($response===FALSE){
   echo 'sorry error occured';
}
else{
    echo $response;
}

?>
```

> the output is 127
>   the version i am using is 1.41 and the output '127' is something that i cant understand

can somebody guide me?

> edit

Actually, i was trying to generate dynamic pdf by filling a pdf form, my passthru was

```
 passthru("/usr/local/bin/pdftk hud3.pdf fill_form result.pdf output - flatten");
```

this was returning nothing

although header before the statement pops up for download, and I press save button to save it on local, it was not saving it on my hard drive. trying to debug the situation, and getting help from already asked question on sktack overflow, i thought to run pdftk first. that's where the above 127 situation rised, need guideline

Comment: If you want to set an environment variable and then call an exec you can't use the `&&` (I think the command right to the `&&` gets called in a subshell and this won't have the env.-var).
Just use `system("PATH=/usr/local/bin/ $command",$response);` or call it the way cjc did suggest (`system("PATH=/usr/local/bin/$command",$response);`).

Comment: Since I don't know pdftk: Does the command work if you execute it on the command line? Where are the `hud3.pdf` and `result.pdf` located? In the same directory as the PHP file?

Comment: yes..all these files are located at the same path..also..trying passthru('/usr/local/bin/pdftk --help') or any other command is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856406/what-is-wrong-with-me-or-code

Comment: Is PHP `safe_mode` set? If yes, is `/usr/local/bin/` in the `safe_mode_exec_dir`? According to the [PHP passthru doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) you should, in case PHP `safe_mode` is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

1) Don't compile your own pdftk and stick it in /usr/local/bin/.  You should use packages instead.  The pdftk package is available in the RPMForge repo:

```
$ yum info pdftk
Loaded plugins: priorities, ps
Available Packages
Name        : pdftk
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.44
Release     : 2.el6.rf
Size        : 906 k
Repo        : rpmforge
Summary     : PDF Tool Kit
URL         : http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/
License     : GPL
Description : If PDF is electronic paper, then pdftk is an electronic staple-remover,
            : hole-punch, binder, secret-decoder-ring, and X-Ray-glasses. Pdftk is a simple
            : tool for doing everyday things with PDF documents. Keep one in the top drawer
            : of your desktop and use it to:
```

In fact, if your "whereis" is returning what you're showing, pdftk is already installed.  Run `rpm -qa |grep pdftk`.  If you don't get anything, install it via yum (look at http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge to see how to add RPMForge to the available repos).  In any case, remove the one you compiled.

2) Your `system` statement in PHP is: "PATH=/usr/local/bin/ && pdftk --help".  This will set the PATH to only /usr/local/bin and then execute `pdftk --help` if it finds it in the PATH.  The return code 127 is from bash, and indicates that it could not find pdftk (which is weird, because you're specifying the one and only PATH, but that's a different matter) or maybe the "&&" confused the PHP system function.  Anyway, why not just use: `system("/usr/local/bin/pdftk --help", $response)`?

Comment: system("/usr/local/bin/pdftk --help", $response)? return still the same 127,,,what should I do now?

Comment: Does passthru('/usr/local/bin/pdftk') return anything?  Running it from the command line returns the command synopsis.

Comment: it returns nothin in php,,in command..when I go to bin, and run dir ..it shows that pdftk is there

Comment: I was going to suggest posting to Stackoverflow, since this seems to be a PHP issue rather than a systems issue, but you've already done so.

Comment: please see comments below the question

Answer (score 2):

The function `system` returns the status code of the executed command not the actual string output. You can check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php). So, the value `127` is the exit status of the executed command.

To get the text output, you need to use [shell_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).